# How to i write an Mp3 file Data into multiple byte arrays in java?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read an Mp3 file from USB and write the data into different buffers. Please help me if there's any good way to do this.

I could read the whole data into a byte array. But i want to do something like writing the first 8 byte into first byte array and next 8 byte into second byte array and so on till end of the data. Please provide a sample code if possible. As i can grasp very fast if i have any example in front of me.

Below is my code which i have to read the data.

```
public class ReadFileInByteArrayWithFileInputStream {
    static byte[] buffer1 ;

    @SuppressWarnings("null")

    public static void main() {
        File file = new File("/mnt/media/wayfaring_stranger.mp3");
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        FileOutputStream fout=null;


        try 
        {
            // create FileInputStream object
            fin = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            // Reads up to certain bytes of data from this input stream into an
            // array of bytes.
            fin.read(fileContent);
            // create string from byte array
            String s = new String(fileContent);
            System.out.println("File content: " + s);

            buffer1 = new byte[8];



        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("File not found" + e);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception while reading file " + ioe);
        }
        finally {

            // close the streams using close method
            try 
            {
                if (fin != null) {
                    fin.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) 
            {
                System.out.println("Error while closing stream: " + ioe);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, Stackoverflow is not a code repository so you can't ask for code/samples.

Comment: file.length() returns the length of the abstract path. don't use it

Comment: Your code is broken to start with, as you're not using the return value of `fin.read(buffer)` (which may not have read all the data) and you're then converting this arbitrary binary data into a string, when it's *not text*. Oh, and the `file.length()` part, too...

Comment: @PareshMayani: It's fine to ask for help with code - it's *not* fine to just say, "I can't be bothered to try anything myself, please give me the code" - which isn't quite the case here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Agree sir. but here in this case he should have posted logcat output or issue he is exactly facing.

Comment: Sorry if my question is of poor standard. Problem is i just dont know how to do it. So i have not tried to divide the data into different buffers. I am very new into Java.

Comment: @PareshMayani: There's no relevant logcat - as far as I can tell he's stuck by not knowing how to create multiple buffers. But saying that "you can't ask for code/samples" on Stack Overflow is simply untrue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, splitting a large file into buffers *that* small will be incredibly wasteful of memory. The overhead for each object will be about the same size (or greater than) the data itself. However, the idea of splitting an input stream into multiple chunks is not inherently problematic.

I think the concept you're missing is using a *collection* of buffers rather than having a separate variable for each one. So instead of having `buffer1`, `buffer2`, `buffer3` etc each of which is a `byte[]` variable, you'd have a single `List<byte[]>` variables called `buffers` (or whatever).

Here's some code to do the reading:

```
public static List<byte[]> readBuffers(InputStream input, int maxBufferSize)
        throws IOException {
    List<byte[]> ret = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    while (true) { 
        byte[] buffer = new byte[maxBufferSize];          
        int bufferRead = 0;
        while (bufferRead < buffer.length) {
            int chunk = input.read(buffer, bufferRead, buffer.length - bufferRead);
            if (chunk == -1) {
                // End of data.

                // If there's no data in this buffer, our list is fine. Otherwise
                // we need to create a smaller buffer and add that.
                if (bufferRead != 0) {
                    byte[] finalBuffer = new byte[bufferRead];
                    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, finalBuffer, 0, bufferRead);
                    ret.add(finalBuffer);
                }
                return ret;
            }
        }
        // Full buffer. Add it to the list, and start again.
        ret.add(buffer);
    }
}
```

Note how:

- We *always* use the return value of `InputStream.read`. Never ignore it, as it's not guaranteed that it will read as much data as you asked for in a single call.
- We *don't* try to convert the data into a string. Unless you're genuinely reading bytes which were originally text data, you shouldn't use the `String` constructor - and if you *are* reading bytes which were originally text data, you should specify the encoding.

Alternatively, if you're actually just trying to pass each chunk of the file to some other function - for hashing, for example - you don't need to have the whole file in memory at all. Instead, you'd encapsulate the idea of "a chunk processor" and pass it into the method. Where I'm adding to a list in the method above, you'd call the chunk processor instead.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am trying to follow your method. I ll get back if this works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
buffer = new byte[8];
                  input.read(buffer);
           //     input.read(buffer, offset, length);
                  Log.i("TvPlayerFunctionalTestApp", "buffer: "+ Arrays.toString(buffer));
                  buffer1 = new byte[8];
                  input.read(buffer1);
```

Comment: How about the above method i have used. It gives me exactly what i needed. Just tested .

Comment: This code is broken - it *assumes* that the `read` call will always fill the buffer.